# How to validate keys of an array with Laravel Form Request?

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, request

What is the correct way to validate that a param in the request should be in the following format: **array with a key of a certain value, and a boolean value**:

```
"countries" => array:2 [
  "usa" => true
  "canada" => true
]
```

In my Form Request I have the following rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'countries' => ['bail', 'array'],
        'countries.*' => ['string', new ValidateCountries],
        'countries.*.' => ['boolean'],
    ];
}
```

My `ValidateCountries` `passes()` method:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $countries = ["usa", "canada", "uk", "france"];
    return in_array(strtolower($value), $countries);
}
```

Comment: what is `ValidateCountries` doing?

Comment: that's a custom `Rule` with the `passes()` method seen above. basically checking if the value is in an array. ....and by just writing out that, i see i should manipulate the `$attribtute` param in `passes()` instead of the `$value`

Comment: apply that custom rule to `countries` since its the array values you are trying to validate ... and in that rule get the keys from the array and do your check on each one

Comment: if you wanted to use `countries.*` you would have one of those which would check for 'boolean' but you also would need a custom rule that would check the attribute to see if it is in that static array you are checking against

Comment: got it. posting answer now

Answer (score 1):

Got it by accessing the `$attribute` param instead of the `$value`. Easy one, but my brain is fried.

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $attribute = explode(".", $attribute)[1];
    $countries = ["usa", "canada", "france", "uk"];
    return in_array(strtolower($attribute), $countries);
}
```

Comment: maybe `last(explode('.', $attribute)` in case you have a different level of nesting in the future?